# Rsync - Files with same file ending

Tags: rsync

I have these JSON files in a large directory structure. Some are just "abc.json" and some the added ".finished". I want to rsync only the files without ".finished".

```
$ find
.
./a
./a/abc.json.finished
./a/abc.json                <-- this file
./a/index.html
./a/somefile.css
./b
./b/abc.json.finished
./b/abc.json                <-- this file
```

Sample rsync command that copies all the "abc.json" AND the "abc.json.finished". I just want the "abc.json".

```
$ rsync --exclude="finished" --include="*c.json" --recursive \
    --verbose --dry-run . server:/tmp/rsync
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/rsync
./
a/
a/abc.json
a/abc.json.finished
a/index.html
a/somefile.css
b/
b/abc.json
b/abc.json.finished

sent 212 bytes  received 72 bytes  113.60 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

---

**Update:** Added more files to the folders. HTML files, CSS and other files are present in my scenario. Only files ending in "c.json" should be transferred.

Scenario can be recreated with the following commands:

```
mkdir a
touch a/abc.json.finished
touch a/abc.json
touch a/index.html
touch a/somefile.css
mkdir b
touch b/abc.json.finished
touch b/abc.json
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command. It assumes that you also want to replicate the source directory tree, *(for any directories containing files which end with `c.json`)*, in the destination location:

`$ rsync --include="*c.json" --exclude="*.*" --recursive \
    --verbose --dry-run . server:/tmp/rsync`

Explanation of command:

- **`--include="*c.json"`** includes only assets whose name **ends** with `c.json`
- **`--exclude="*.*"`** excludes all other assets (i.e. assets whose name includes a dot `.`)
- **`--recursive`** recurse into directories.
- **`--verbose`** log the results to the console.
- **`--dry-run`** shows what would have been copied, without actually copying the files. This option/flag should be omitted to actually perform the *copy* task.
- **`.`** the path to the source directory.
- **`server:/tmp/rsync`** the path to the destination directory.

---

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the command provided above also copies files whose filename does not include a dot character. To avoid this consider utlizing both `rsync` and `find` as follows:

`$ rsync --dry-run --verbose --files-from=<(find ./ -name "*c.json") \
    ./ server:/tmp/rsync`

This utilizes process substitution, i.e. `<(list)`, to pass the output from the `find` command to the `--files-from=` option/flag of the `rsync` command.

---

**source tree**

```
.
├── a
│   ├── abc.json
│   ├── abc.json.finished.json
│   ├── index.html
│   └── somefile.css
└── b
    ├── abc.json
    └── abc.json.finished.json
```

**resultant destination tree**

```
server
└── tmp
     └── rsync
        ├── a
        │   └── abc.json
        └── b
            └── abc.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works if there are no other files present. I expanded the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is **use grep** and **create a file containing all file names** we want to transfer.

```
find |grep "c.json$" > rsync-files
rsync --files-from=rsync-files --verbose --recursive --compress --dry-run \
    ./ \
    server:/tmp/rsync
rm rsync-files
```

Content of **'rsync-files'**:

```
./a/abc.json
./b/abc.json
```

**Output** when running **rsync** command:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/rsync
./
a/
a/abc.json
b/
b/abc.json
```